# Using CURSOR expression in WITH Clause in query Oracle 12.1

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a strange issue where the data showing up in Cursor is **incorrect**. Below is the table and the query. But when I replace the `CURSOR (Select * from H)` with CURSOR( actual query of H ) , it works

```
   Tab1              Tab2
Col1  Col2        Col3  Col4
----------        ----------
1     A            1     A
2     B            2     B
3     C            6     F
4     D            7     G
5     E            8     H

WITH  H AS (SELECT * FROM tab1
              WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tab2 WHERE col1 = col3)
             )
       K AS (SELECT count(*) cnt FROM H) 
 SELECT cnt, CURSOR(SELECT * FROM H) result FROM K;
```

Output of above query give Cnt = 3 and cursor has data as below which is incorrect. But when you just run Select * from H , you get the correct output i.e. 3, 4, 5 rows

```
Col1  col2
---   ---
 1     A
 2     B
```

Comment: Fascinating. I reproduced this on my local 18c database. Unfortunately [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e7aa48e8dae1ffc75c599956fa83aef2) can't cope with the inline `cursor` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per this [article](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/with-clause) Subquery refactoring either uses a global temporary table or an inline view.

In your case, it may be using a global temporary table and I guess the CURSOR keyword does something implicit with the global temporary table.

Try using the INLINE hint and see if it works

```
WITH  H AS (SELECT  /*+ INLINE */ a.* FROM tab1 a
          WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tab2 WHERE col1 = col3)
         )
```

Comment: The `/*+ INLINE */` hint solves the problem but it's not clear why it should.

Comment: i think CURSOR keyword does something implicit with the global temporary table

Comment: Thanks Saraj and APC .Very strange behavior, this was not a complex inline query so does it infer every time we have to use the hint if CURSOR is involved or should it be reported to Oracle Support

Comment: Report it to Oracle support and use INLINE hint till the issue is fixed by oracle support

Comment: Please accept the solution if it had resolved your problem so that ppl with similar problem have reference